# Any difference between `Reader a (b -> c)` and `b -> Reader a c`?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, reader-monad

(Some other mtl monads would bring up the same problem, but let's just use `Reader` here to exemplify)

Say I need to show something in a human-readable way, with the implementation and behaviour details depending on the user preferences, read from a configuration:

```hs
showIt :: Config -> Object -> String
```

Where the user configuration is merely read and not to be modified, so might as well use `Reader` to reflect that:

```hs
showIt :: Reader Config (Object -> String)
```

But wait, how is that different from this:

```hs
showIt :: Object -> Reader Config String
```

Though I hardly know `Reader`, I do have tried both designs and they seem functionally equivalent. I still wonder if there would be a semantic difference in between, that is, when some other Haskellers look at my code, would they interpret a different purpose or meaning if I had used the other design instead?
If so, then which usage should be preferred in scenarios like this?

Comment: Which way is more idiomatic in Haskell?

Comment: @RobertHarvey ...both?

Comment: Please avoid opinion-based questions

Comment: @Noughtmare changed the tone, hopefully not sound like looking for opinions...

Comment: Receiving a `Config` as an ordinary function argument is not any more or less "read-only" than using `Reader Config`. In both cases the `Config` is an immutable value so it obviously is not modified in the sense of actual mutation. In both cases the computation can call `Config`-dependent sub-computations with alternate values of the `Config` (by simply passing a different one in the case of ordinary function arguments, or using things like `local` in the case of `Reader`). `Reader` doesn't mean "read-only", it's just meant to indicate that you have implicit access to some value.

Comment: All three types you mentioned and two you didn't are isomorphic: `C -> O -> S`, `Reader C (O -> S)`, `O -> Reader C S`, `C -> Reader O S`, and `Reader O (C -> S)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Not to mention `(C, O) -> S` and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is `Reader Config (Object -> String)` different from `Object -> Reader Config String`?

The former limits the `showIt` implementation to `read` a config only once, and then produce a string conversion function that must work for all objects. The latter allows the implementation to decide what config to read (or rather, whether to read<sup>1</sup>) depending on the input object.

Their usage patterns are quite different:

```
do
  showAny <- showIt
  let str1 = showAny object1
  let str2 = showAny object2
  return (str1 ++ " " ++ str2)
```

vs

```
do
  let show1 = showIt object1
  let show2 = showIt object2
  str1 <- show1
  str2 <- show2
  return (str1 ++ " " ++ str2)
```

<sub>1: with the `Reader` monad, there is no much choice - you can only decide whether to read the config or not (or: how often to read it - but it'll be the same every time). With other monads, where reading different bits of the configuration might involve different file system or database accesses etc, the difference will become larger.</sub>

Comment: In fact I'd say "read only once" isn't a well-defined notion in Haskell. There's no reliable way to observe how often a value is used. What _can_ be discussed is whether it's used at all, but even then the proposed difference doesn't really hold up: consider `hesitate = Reader $ \l flag -> if flag then head l else 0`. This will only read the "configuration" list if the inner function is passed `True`, so that `runReader hesitate [] True = ⊥`. On the other hand, `runReader hesitate [] False = 0`. I still agree with your argument, but really only for the generalised setting of _any monad_.

Comment: You say their usage patterns are quite different, but to me those look very similar. They're even more similar if you write `do { show1 <- showIt; show2 <- showIt; let str1 = show1 object1; let str2 = show2 object2; return (str ++ " " ++ str2)` for the first one.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I was thinking of `hesitate flag = if flag then ask else return 0` (rather than `hesitate flag = (\c -> if flag then c else 0) <$> ask`), where `runReader (hesitate True) undefined` reads (and fails) whereas `runReader (hesitate False) undefined` does not read and return 0.

Comment: I would inline the `show1` and `show2` bindings in the second code block, even in more complicated cases.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, but `<-` vs `=` makes a large difference regarding the types. Try refactoring them to use a helper function `helper showAny = (showAny object1) ++ " " ++ (showAny object2)` - this is not possible in the second snippet, where you always need to drag around the `Reader` context to be able to use `showIt`.

Comment: @Bergi "Not possible" seems too strong a claim to me. `do { config <- ask; return (helper (flip (runReader . showIt) config)) }`

Comment: @DanielWagner Yeah, you can pass a new function that runs `runReader` on a newly constructed context, but that works only for the `Reader` monad.

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary to the other answer, these are all the same thing.

`Reader a b` is just a `newtype` wrapper for `a -> b`,

```hs
newtype Reader a b = Reader (a -> b)
```

meaning that `Reader a b` has exactly the same capabilities as `a -> b` - it's just a different API. And since `a -> b -> c` is just another way of writing `a -> (b -> c)`, you can see that these are all just different ways of writing the same thing:

```hs
Reader Config (Object -> String)
Config -> (Object -> String)
Config -> Object -> String
```

Your last example is still morally the same type as the others. The order in which a function accepts its arguments is immaterial - you could just as easily have written it the other way around:

```hs
Object -> Reader Config String
Object -> (Config -> String)
Object -> Config -> String
Config -> Object -> String  -- flip the arguments
```

Code using `Reader` happens to be written in a certain style (that is, using `do` notation, `runReader`, and friends), but that's really just a distraction - it's the *behaviour* which we actually care about.

There certainly are other (non-`Reader`) monads for which these types are not equivalent, but that's a different question!